# Page zooming out on click

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, contacts

I have an issue, the contact page zooms out on devices such iPad and mobile phones when I click to the link or just tap and scroll to it. 
The page it works fine on laptops. 
Can anyone understand the reason why by reading the code below?

this is the Html code:

```
<section id="contact">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="containerinner">
                <div class="wow slideInRight animated"> 
                    <h1>Keep In Touch</h1> 
                </div>  
            </div>              
            <div id="contactcontainer">
                <div class="intro">
                    <p>
                    You can drop me a line directly to: <ahref="mailto:dan.rosbert@gmail.com">dan.rosbert@gmail.com</a>.
                    <br>
                    Otherwise you can fill the form below.
                    <br>
                    Available from now.
                    </p>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <form action="contact.php" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend></legend>
                        <div class="controlgroup">
                            <label for="form1_name">Name *</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your full name*" name="name" value>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controlgroup">
                            <label for="form1_email">Email *</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a valid email address*" name="email" value>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controlgroup">
                            <label for="form1_services">Services Required</label>
                                <select id="form1_services" name="services">
                                    <option value="Website Design"> Website Design (from scratch) </option>
                                    <option value="Resposive Design"> Responsive Design </option>
                                    <option value="Customize a Site"> Customize a Site </option>
                                    <option value="Quotation"> Quotation </option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controlgroup">
                            <label>Project Info*</label>
                            <textarea placeholder="Hi there, I am contacting you because...*" id="msg" name="msg" required aria-required="true"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="send" value="Hit me up!" class="wow flash animated" data-wow-delay="2s">
                    </fieldset>         
                </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your head tag to stop zooming on mobile devices

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Hi Nakib, your solution didn't sort the issue. I already had <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> in the head. This issue happens only on this contact page. The others are ok. That's what confuses me.